# Retrieving youtube video location tag using youtube API 3.0

Tags: c#, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am having some issues with retrieving video location tag from Youtube API. The tag was set on the

[image: This is here I set the video location tag] Below is the method that I have attempted where I can't see the video location tag appearing in my data.

```
 var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(initialiser);
 var ListRequest = new Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.PlaylistItemsResource.ListRequest(youtubeService, "");
 ListRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
 ListRequest.PlaylistId = _PlayListID; var playlistItemsListResponse = playlistItemsListRequest.Execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apear to be using the [Playlistitems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) method which

> Returns a collection of playlist items that match the API request parameters. You can retrieve all of the playlist items in a specified playlist or retrieve one or more playlist items by their unique IDs.

[PlaylistItems resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource)  Which does not contain any information about the location of the play list item.

[Video.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) returns a list of videos which used to have a `locationDescription` property which has been deprecated  since [June 1, 2017](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#release_notes_06_01_2017)

The only property that remains that appears to have any information about the location of a video would be `recordingDetails`  You will have to check wht that contains.  but again this is on a video not a play list item.

> The recordingDetails object encapsulates information about the location, date and address where the video was recorded.